# DMS (document management system) in which I can use my own branding

Tags: images, document-management, thumbnail

A client of ours needs a shared file and storage management solution. It should serve some 10 different users (in separate locations), and be able to grow in the near future. It must have roles user and admin access.

We plan to use no more than 50Gb at a time (there may be some short videos and final arts). I believe it won't have to handle much traffic (probably one access per day).

The interface should be simple enough to be used by non-technical personnel, keep contents separated by users and categories and be able to show at a glance the contents of the different files, preferably in a graphic manner (thumbnails of images and PDFs, different icons for different content types...).

It could be a hosted solution or on own (rented) server, that's not a problem. What is IMPORTANT is it to be presented, in case it is a hosted solution, in a co-branded manner, so that our client can only see their corporate image on the application, and not the image (nor URLs, etc.) of the application creators.

Comment: I worked with Alfresco. There is a community edition which is Open Source. I have a feeling it could help, especially with Alfresco Share, but I lack experience with this one, so I am not sure you can remove all references to Alfresco from the interface. Since [Nicolas mentioned CMIS](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/23155/13731), [Alfresco also implements it](https://www.alfresco.com/cmis). Maybe someone can elaborate on this lead.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be the perfect case for [OwnCloud](https://owncloud.org/). This is a free, open source solution on the LAMP stack, which you may host on your own servers, or use one of the many hosted offerings.

- You may have many users, and give each of them as much storage as
  needed.
- The admin account is separate of course.
- Not sure about categories, but you may have a folder based structure.
- With themes,  you may create the branding you/your customers like.
- Web Interface with previews

At the end, this is much like any other cloud storage, but you MAY host it on your servers.

Answer (score 0):

[NemakiWare](http://nemakiware.com) is an Open Source document management system that fits your requirements.

- Thumbnails of images and PDFs (and even preview so that you can have a look without downloading)
- Simple interface
- Branding can be modified, using your own logo/name
- You can host it on your own server, hosted is possible too
- Support 50GB and more
- Content can be organized with tags
- Each user can have their own folder, collaboration folders can also be created, groups can be defined for efficient access control management

In addition, NemakiWare is based on the [CMIS standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Management_Interoperability_Services), so you can access it with any [CMIS client](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Management_Interoperability_Services#Client_applications) of your choice.

*Disclaimer: I worked on NemakiWare.*

Comment: Thank you **Nicolas Raoul**. The only CON I find is about something I didn't explained. I have no knowledge beyond installations on LAMP systems so I'd need extra help for a - Java 1.6+ - Apache Tomcat 7+ - Solr 4+ - Couch DB 1.0.4+ architecture. Despite it I'm gonna give it a try on a ready-installed demo and, in case it fits my needs, I'll ask for help to have it installed.